# How can I take a sensitive result for this equation?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there any sensitive equation solver which will not show the result as approximately 0 for this equation:

$cosx=e^{-\frac{x}{10^{45}}}$

being x is variable, or how can I calculate it?

Answer (score 5):

Using the same idea as Alan Turing, using Taylor expansion to $O\left(x^3\right)$ we have $$\cos (x)-e^{-\frac{x}{a}}=\frac{x}{a}-\left(\frac{1}{2 a^2}+\frac{1}{2}\right) x^2+O\left(x^3\right) $$ and solving the quadratic, beside the trivial solution $x=0$, there is $$x_0=\frac{2 a}{1+a^2}$$

Coding Newton method in a double precision Fortran program for $a=10^{45}$, only one iteration can be performed and the first and last iterate is $$x_1=   1.99999999999999996830000\times 10^{-45}$$ The calculations stop because the derivative is computed to be $0$.

I suppose that using extended precision will allow more significant figures.

**Edit**

Consider the equation $$f(x)=\cos(x)-e^{-\frac{x}{a}}$$ and perform one iteration of Newton (or halley or Householder) method  starting at $x_0=\frac{2 a}{1+a^2}$ Comuting the first iterate $x_1$, write it as $$x_1=x_0\left(1-\frac{f(x_0)}{x_0\,f'(x_0)}\right)$$ and call $\epsilon$ the machine accuracy. Developing the term in bracket as Taylor series around $a=0$, it is sure that we shall start to be in trouble as soon as $$\frac1{3a^2} <\epsilon\implies a >\frac 1{\sqrt{3\epsilon}}$$ Using $\epsilon=10^{-19}$ as in the Fortran environment I used, this means that problem will start as soon as $a >2 \times 10^{9}$. So, the result given above does not mean anyhing except that is is an inacurrate estimate of the starting value itself.

Comment: Yes, this is perfect right answer. Thanks.

Comment: +1 because you corrected me, an thank you for quoting the method I used ^^

Comment: P.s. I just noticed the OP changed the equations!

Comment: @AlanTuring. I did ,ot check the edit and, so, ignored that the question changed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a transcendental equation, so your best bet is to use numerical methods to approximate the solution. Of course, the presence of $10^{45}$ there will surely result in an answer very close to zero.

Comment: Notice that $x = 0$ holds as a solution, even if trivial!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you may try a Taylor expansion, in order to see if you can find a small solution:

$$\cos x \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \ldots$$

$$e^{x/a} \approx 1 + \frac{x}{a} + \frac{x^2}{2a^2} + \ldots$$

Where I called $a$ your numerical coefficient.

Hence your equation becomes

$$1 - \frac{x^2}{2} = 1 + \frac{x}{a} + \frac{x^2}{2a^2}$$

Which is a second degree equation (because we stopped at second order of approximation!)

$$\frac{x^2}{2a^2} + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x}{a} = 0$$

Hence you may collect an $x$

$$x\left(\frac{x}{2a^2} + \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{a}\right) = 0$$

Of course the solution $x = 0$ holds, since

$$\cos 0 = 1$$

$$e^0 = 1$$

Then you have another solution which is the bracket equals to zero:

$$\frac{(1+a^2)x}{2a^2} = \frac{-1}{a}$$

$$x = -\frac{2a}{1+a^2}$$

In any case, at least you have one sure trivial solution which is $x = 0$

**EDIT**

Since the OP changed the equations, this holds no more, but it's sufficient to use the expansion for the negative exponent:

$$e^{-x/a} \approx 1 - \frac{x}{a} + \frac{x^2}{2a^2} + \ldots$$

Comment: Thanks. It will be enough I think

Comment: Btu I noticed that the equation is wrong. I corrected it.

Comment: Your expansion of $\cos(x)$ seems to be unusual.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Gosh! You're right! Let me correct haha! Thanks!

Comment: @user383233 My answer held for the old equations. For your new equations I can tell you that the trivial easy solution $x = 0$ holds. In addition to that, you may try to use my method by expanding the exponential:

$$e^{-x/a} \approx 1 - \frac{x}{a} + \frac{x^2}{2a^2} + \ldots$$

Comment: I just said *unusual* (but interesting - joke). Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Haha :D